# Filter dataframe based on rownames

Tags: r

Is there a way to filter dataframe based on rownames. For example shown below. First 3 rows are mandatory, then last 3 rows are conditions. So, there is false and negative values only, those should be displayed

```
    ColA
ABC FALSE
GDF 1
ASD True
dsa FALSE
gfd -1
poi TRUE
```

Expected Output (Only last row should be removed since it is true)

```
    ColA
ABC FALSE
GDF 1
ASD True
dsa FALSE
gfd -1
```

```
structure(list(col1 = structure(c(3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("-1", 
"1", "False", "True"), class = "factor")), .Names = "col1", row.names = c("ABC", 
"GDF", "ASD", "dsa", "gfd", "poi"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You cannot have duplicate rownames in a dataframe. Can you share data using `dput` ?

Comment: No No. That was only for Demo. Just to make understand. First 3 rows are mandatory and last 3 are conditions

Comment: But your title says `Filter dataframe based on rownames`, so you don't want it based on rownames but positions?

Comment: OK let me edit it :)

Comment: Edited. So only last row should removed since it is true

Comment: simply try `df[-6,]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try :

```
mandatory_rows <- 3
subset(df, seq_len(nrow(df)) <= mandatory_rows | col1 != 'True')

#     col1
#ABC False
#GDF     1
#ASD  True
#dsa False
#gfd    -1
```

Comment: or `subset(df, !rownames(df) %in% c("dsa", "gfd", "poi") | df$col1 != "TRUE")`

Comment: Great , I just added anothere condition `````subset(asd, !rownames(asd) %in% c("dsa", "gfd", "poi") | ( asd$col1 != "True" |  asd$col1 != "0"))````` In case if the number is greater than 0, this row should also be removed. But this did not work. :(

Answer (score 0):

We could use `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     filter((!as.logical(col1))| row_number() <= 3)
```